# Can a MacBook Air's Delete key be remapped to "power on"?

Tags: macos, macbook, remapping

For my new MacBook Air, the power-on button requires many tries. Can the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key be remapped to be the power-on button?

Comment: You say it's new, so get it repaired under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't remap your power-on button to the Delete key at startup. Although, you could do so when you are logged in using an app such as Karabiner.

If your MacBook air is new, I suggest you to bring it to an Apple Authorized Service Provider for maintenance. They have diagnostic tools to test your keyboard and if your computer is under warranty, they will replace the top case.